# Flatten PNG image with ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick, magick++

Using shell commands, I can perform the following on a PNG file that has transparency:

```
convert image.png -background Black -flatten image.png
```

And the resulting image now has a black background.  How do I do this with the Magick++ API?  I have an Image object that I'm using already for some other manipulation:

```
Image img(filename);
img.resize(Magick::Geometry("x48"));
img.unsharpmask(5.0, 0.5, 50.0, 50.0);
img.gamma(0.5);
...
```

Before I do the resizing, I need to take care of the image transparency and make it black instead.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The -flatten option can be found in STL.h and is called flattenImages. This method requires a container of images. Below is an example of how you can use the method.

```cpp
Image img(filename);

Geometry size(img.columns(), img.rows());
Color color(0,0,0);
Image black(size, color);

std::list<Image> images;
images.push_back(black);
images.push_back(img);

Image flattenedImage;
flattenImages(&flattenedImage, images.begin(), images.end());

flattenedImage.resize(Geometry("x48"));
```

Comment: Wow, I wasn't expecting it to be so elaborate, but it works as expected.  Thanks.  I was going to post that it still wasn't working but then I realized, in my own uber stroke of genius, I was reading in a PNG, performing the changes, then writing out a temp file to verify ... as a JPG!  Some of the images were getting horribly mangled that way.  Once I realized my error, everything works!  Now I need to write a case switch so it ignores JPEG files and only processes PNG, GIF, and TIFF files.  Thanks again!